# Update table values from another Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a table that is roughly 20000 rows in size and 52 columns. At times, I need to update a percentage of select rows at once. I'm hoping to use a macro to update the select cells based on a value in the row, mapped out by a second smaller table with the updated values to be entered in to table 1. Almost like a VLOOKUP function, but one that doesn't erase the cell if the entry isn't found. For example, change the Phone Number according to the Host ID.

I tried to do this with an Array in the code below for a specfic set of the values in Table 1, but my values didn't update. My VBA is a bit rusty, so if someone can review and assist with getting this to function, it would be appreciated. I would like to make it update any entry in the table based on the table headers eventually.

```
Sub NewNameandCostCenter()
Dim myList, myRange
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Set sht = Worksheets("NewNameMacro")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("ALL")
Set StartCell = Range("A2")

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'set myList array
Set myList = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
LastRow2 = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
'set myRange array
Set myRange = Sheets("ALL").Range("J2:M" & LastRow2)
'Update values of cells adjacent
For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole
myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 2).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole
myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 3).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole
Next cel
End Sub
```

Thanks,
JD

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you're effectively running an UPDATE query against your data, based on the values in your mapping table.

I've assumed the following:

- The "key" column is the first column in your data table *and* in your mapping table.
- The columns in your mapping table are in the same order and relative position as the columns in the data table (although this could easily be adjusted.
- The order of the keys in the mapping table and the data table is unsorted. If you can ensure that the keys are sorted (ideally in both sheets), then you could achieve substantially better performance with some slight modifications.

I've hard-coded the ranges in my example, but you can reinstate the last row and last column approach if you need to.

I've done all of my comparisons between arrays instead of ranges, and I've done away with the Find approach. You'll find that this works, and works much more efficiently.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewNameandCostCenter()

  Dim start As Double
  start = Timer

  Dim countOfChangedRows As Long

  'set rngMap array
  Dim rngMap As Range
  Set rngMap = Worksheets("Map").Range("A1:D51")

  'set rngData array
  Dim rngData As Range
  Set rngData = Worksheets("Data").Range("J2:M20001")

  Dim aMap As Variant
  aMap = rngMap.Value

  Dim aData As Variant
  aData = rngData.Value

  Dim mapRow As Long
  Dim datarow As Long
  Dim mapcol As Long

  For mapRow = LBound(aMap, 1) To UBound(aMap, 1)
    For datarow = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
      'Check the key matches in both tables
      If aData(datarow, 1) = aMap(mapRow, 1) Then
        countOfChangedRows = countOfChangedRows + 1
        'Assumes the columns in map and data match
        For mapcol = LBound(aMap, 2) + 1 To UBound(aMap, 2)
          aData(datarow, mapcol) = aMap(mapRow, mapcol)
        Next mapcol
      End If
    Next datarow
  Next mapRow

  rngData.Value = aData

  Debug.Print countOfChangedRows & " of "; UBound(aData, 1) & " rows updated in " & Timer - start & " seconds"

End Sub
```

The performance is reasonable for 50 updated rows:

`50 of 20000 rows updated in 0.23828125 seconds`

But if you need to start updating thousands of rows, then you would benefit greatly from ensuring the data is sorted and tweaking the code accordingly.