# Synchronizing Excel Tables

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables in excel, a master and a data table.
The data table contains certain updated records that need to be updated in the master. I found a macro that does this job perfectly, except that after updating, it converts the table to a range and removes the table.

Any help in modifying how to retain the table but still update changes?

[Source of the macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795107/update-table-values-from-another-table)

**The code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewNameandCostCenter()

Dim start As Double
start = Timer

Dim countOfChangedRows As Long

'set rngMap array
Dim rngMap As Range
Set rngMap = Worksheets("Map").Range("A1:D51")

'set rngData array
Dim rngData As Range
Set rngData = Worksheets("Data").Range("J2:M20001")

Dim aMap As Variant
aMap = rngMap.Value

Dim aData As Variant
aData = rngData.Value

Dim mapRow As Long
Dim datarow As Long
Dim mapcol As Long

For mapRow = LBound(aMap, 1) To UBound(aMap, 1)
For datarow = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
  'Check the key matches in both tables
  If aData(datarow, 1) = aMap(mapRow, 1) Then
    countOfChangedRows = countOfChangedRows + 1
    'Assumes the columns in map and data match
    For mapcol = LBound(aMap, 2) + 1 To UBound(aMap, 2)
      aData(datarow, mapcol) = aMap(mapRow, mapcol)
    Next mapcol
  End If
Next datarow
Next mapRow

rngData.Value = aData

Debug.Print countOfChangedRows & " of "; UBound(aData, 1) & " rows updated in " & Timer - start & " seconds"

End Sub
```

Comment: The line *rngData.Value = aData* makes everything Values only, note that *aData = rngData.Value* from earlier in the code.  I am not seeing where the table is being Removed, from the code, unless the previous data is being used to re-overwrite the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ***Quick Edit*** on a **copy** of your workbook. It's been edited to make changes directly into the master table, instead of pulling the data into an array and then pasting the edited copy back.

---

**Explanation**

The existing code being used had a couple of steps:

1. Pull data from ranges into arrays
2. Compare arrays and edit `aData` (array from sheet Data) to match `aMap` (array from sheet Map)
3. Paste updated array `aData` back into the ranges it came from

The issue you had came from pasting the array data back into the worksheet range. This could be worked around by making changes directly into the table instead of making the changes to an array to be pasted back in.

In VBA, you can access a table object using a worksheet's `ListObjects` collection and either the index or name of the desired Table object. This list object has various useful collections; `.ListRows`, `.ListColumns`, `.DataBodyRange`, etc. (I think there may also be a headers range?). For most tables I find the `.ListRows` to be most helpful.

One of the properties of a ListRow (or a ListColumn) is its `.Range` feature. It requires a row and a column variable (similar to the `.Cells` from a worksheet). For this particular situation (in which the code is cycling through the Tables ListRows collection - `For each datarow in rngData.ListRows`), the datarow will only ever hold one row, so the row variable is a constant 1. The column variable was the same variable/value used when accessing the data from the array. (Although I had forgotten the array might be zero-based, so I guess we got lucky on that one).

Another aspect of the ListRows and ListColumns collections is the `.Count` property. I used this in a few places:

1. Assigning the `mapcol` the proper range of values to access the values from every column of the ListRows
2. To get the total number of ListRows in the table for the `Debug.Print` statement at the end of the code

Having access to each range in each ListRow via `.Range`, the code was able to:

1. Pull data from the "Map" range into an array
2. Compare the "Map" array to the Master table, and edit the Master table appropriately.

The code could also be rewritten, so instead of pulling any of the data into arrays, it just does a direct comparison between one table and the next (you can see that done in the ***Edited Code*** below).

---

**Quick Edit**

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewNameandCostCenter()

Dim start As Double
start = Timer

Dim countOfChangedRows As Long

'set rngMap array
Dim rngMap As Range
Set rngMap = Worksheets("Map").Range("A1:D51")

'set rngData table (previously set rngData array)
Dim rngData As ListObject
Set rngData = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("TableName") 'Adjust to name of your master table

Dim aMap As Variant
aMap = rngMap.Value

Dim mapRow As Long
Dim datarow As ListRow 'For cycling through the table rows
Dim mapcol As Long

For mapRow = LBound(aMap, 1) To UBound(aMap, 1)
For each datarow in rngData.ListRows
  'Check the key matches in both tables
  If datarow.Range(1, 1) = aMap(mapRow, 1) Then
    countOfChangedRows = countOfChangedRows + 1
    'Assumes the columns in map and data match
    For mapcol = LBound(aMap, 2) + 1 To UBound(aMap, 2)
      datarow.Range(1, mapcol) = aMap(mapRow, mapcol)
    Next mapcol
  End If
Next datarow
Next mapRow

Debug.Print countOfChangedRows & " of "; rngData.ListRows.Count & " rows updated in " & Timer - start & " seconds"

End Sub
```

---

**Edited Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewNameandCostCenter()

Dim start As Double
start = Timer

Dim countOfChangedRows As Long

'set rngMap array
Dim rngMap As ListObject
Set rngMap = Worksheets("Map").ListObjects("TableName") 'Adjust to name of your data table

'set rngData table (previously set rngData array)
Dim rngData As ListObject
Set rngData = Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("TableName") 'Adjust to name of your master table

Dim mapRow As ListRow
Dim datarow As ListRow 'For cycling through the table rows
Dim mapcol As Long

For each mapRow in rngMap
For each datarow in rngData.ListRows
  'Check the key matches in both tables
  If datarow.Range(1, 1) = mapRow.Range(1, 1) Then
    countOfChangedRows = countOfChangedRows + 1
    'Assumes the columns in map and data match
    For mapcol = 2 To rngMap.ListColumns.Count
      datarow.Range(1, mapcol) = mapRow.Range(1, mapcol)
    Next mapcol
  End If
Next datarow
Next mapRow

Debug.Print countOfChangedRows & " of "; rngData.ListRows.Count & " rows updated in " & Timer - start & " seconds"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes the code works fine. Can you explain the logic as i'm keep to learn what i was missing.

Comment: @marv I added an explanation. Please let me know if I left any knowledge gaps, so I can try to fill them in.

Comment: The latter approach make it more dynamic and your explanation is quite clear. Thank you again for your help. much appreciated.!!