# Update table values from another Table with variable range

Tags: excel, vba

Basically total beginner in VBA, so here is my problem:

I am trying to combine the two codes from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795107/update-table-values-from-another-table) and i am having problems. With the hardcoded range it works perfectly fine, but as soon as i try to add the last row & column it doesn't work anymore and gives me error runtime error 1004 as soon as the skript reaches aMap = rngMap.Value. Thanks for your help!

Here is my skript:

```
Sub UpdateFile()

  Dim countOfChangedRows As Long
  Dim ULastRow As Long
  Dim ULastColumn As Long
  Dim UStartCell As Range
  Dim USht As Worksheet
  Set UStartCell = Range("A5")
  Set USht = Worksheets("UpdateSheet")
  
  Dim DLastRow As Long
  Dim DLastColumn As Long
  Dim DStartCell As Range
  Dim DSht As Worksheet
  Set DStartCell = Range("A2")
  
If fullpath = "" Then
         MsgBox "Please Select a File"
    Else
        Workbooks.Open fullpath
    End If

  Set DSht = Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet

'Find Update Sheet Last Row and Column
  ULastRow = USht.Cells(USht.Rows.Count, UStartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  ULastColumn = USht.Cells(UStartCell.Row, USht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  
'Find Data Sheet Last Row and Column
  DLastRow = DSht.Cells(DSht.Rows.Count, DStartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  DLastColumn = DSht.Cells(DStartCell.Row, DSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'set rngMap array
  Dim rngMap As Range
  Set rngMap = USht.Range(UStartCell, USht.Cells(ULastRow, ULastColumn))

'set rngData array
  Dim rngData As Range
  Set rngData = DSht.Range(DStartCell, DSht.Cells(DLastRow, DLastColumn))

  Dim aMap As Variant
  aMap = rngMap.Value

  Dim aData As Variant
  aData = rngData.Value

  Dim mapRow As Long
  Dim datarow As Long
  Dim mapcol As Long

  For mapRow = LBound(aMap, 1) To UBound(aMap, 1)
    For datarow = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
      'Check the key matches in both tables
      If aData(datarow, 1) = aMap(mapRow, 1) Then
        countOfChangedRows = countOfChangedRows + 1
        'Assumes the columns in map and data match
        For mapcol = LBound(aMap, 2) + 1 To UBound(aMap, 2)
          aData(datarow, mapcol) = aMap(mapRow, mapcol)
        Next mapcol
      End If
    Next datarow
  Next mapRow

  rngData.Value = aData
  
'Close selected file with saving
  Workbooks(fileName).Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```